# Smartphone screen broken - PC recognizes phone - Save data, unlock phone PIN

Tags: hardware

My smartphone screen has been destroyed in a small accident.

There have been still data on the phone like images, videos, contacts.

If I connect the phone to the PC via USB, the PC recognizes the phone, but I cant access the data because the phone is locked with a PIN.

I cant enter the PIN because the screen is totaly destroyed.

Is there a way to save the data?

Comment: What phone and Android version? Do you have custom recovery installed?

Comment: phone is samsung galaxy s4 mini, android should be 4.3 havent the phone here atm. It is of a friend. I remember that he said he has done something like a recovery mode when he bought it.

Comment: If it has TWRP, try to start it (I don't know the process on S4) and if you can and TWRP is new enough, you should just be able to connect it and browse to things available to MTP like photos and videos, contacts are not accessible though. No real trick to get 4.x to work without screen access though. Is the screen visible at all, meaning use an OTG cable and mouse?